# pass text from file as arguments after running variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've got this example:

```
[nir]$ cat a.cfg 
--arg1 $(./get.sh variable)
[nir]$ cat get.sh 
echo "${1}-info"
[nir]$ cat a.sh 
arg=$(cat a.cfg)

echo "$arg"
[nir]$ ./a.sh
--arg1 $(./get.sh variable)
```

I want the `a.sh` to return `--arg variable-info`. the end result is to switch the `echo` with a real command that takes `a.cfg`, parse it, and send it as the arguments.

Comment: Well, with this example, you could replace the whole thing with just a constant string, since `a.sh` and `a.cfg` don't take any arguments. That's not what you're looking for, but it's hard to tell which parts of the whole thing here can't be modified (e.g. because they're actually third-party commands). I would probably approach that by changing `a.cfg` to a script that outputs the required stuff, so you'd use `arg=$(otherscript.sh)` instead of `arg=$(cat otherfile)`. Running code in there is going to be the end result anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could have in `a.sh`:

```
eval '
arg=$(cat << EOF
'"$(cat a.cfg)"'
EOF
)'
printf '%s\n' "$arg"
```

Which tells the shell to evaluate this shell code:

```
arg=$(cat << EOF
--arg1 $(./get.sh variable)
EOF
)
```

And the `$(...)` will be expanded as it's inside a here-document with unquoted delimiter.

Comment: Looks like a future rabbit hole :) I think I'm going with placeholder and will calculate `./get.sh variable` in the main script. thanks though.